# Xquery to get a string between delimiters

Tags: string, split, substring, xquery

I have (TEI)XML with bits like
`<ref target="#a1"/>` but also `<ref target="#a1 #b2 #c3"/>`
I need to write the xquery code to transform each `#`-target to a link; this is no problem if I have just one `target="#a1"`, then I use `substring-after($node/@target, '#')` and look for `xml-id`s that are the same as the substring, but then of course I get problems if the substring is longer than needed, no match is possible.
Is there a way to select the substring between `#` and `space` or `#` and `"`?
(I am very new to xquery so sorry if I am asking something very obvious, but I could not find an economic solution)

Answer (score 0):

You could [`tokenize()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-tokenize) the attribute value by an optional space `\s` and `#` with this regex `\s?#` and then filter out an empty item with a predicate using `normalize-space()` or testing the string length `string-length(.) gt 0`:

```
let $ref :=  <ref target="#a1 #b2 #c3"/>
let $targets := tokenize($ref/@target, '\s?#')[normalize-space()]
return  
  $targets
```

or you could tokenize by space `\s` or space and # `\s#`, then [`translate()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-translate) any remaining `#` into nothing:

```
let $ref :=  <ref target="#a1 #b2 #c3"/>
let $targets := tokenize($ref/@target, '\s#') ! translate(., '#', '')
return  
  $targets
```

Another way to read the space separated `ref/@target` attribute values as a sequence is to read them as `xs:NMTOKENS` (which are space separated values), and then you just need to worry about removing the `#` from each value:

```
let $ref :=  <ref target="#a1 #b2 #c3"/>
let $target-tokens as xs:NMTOKENS := $ref/@target
let $targets :=  $target-tokens ! translate(., '#', '')
return
  $targets
```

Comment: Thank you! I must have both 'tokenize' for 'gt 1', and else  'substring-after' right? I tried replacing 'substring-after' with 'tokenize' but it does not seem to work

Comment: You don't need to bother testing if there are multiple and different logic with if/else. What I have provided will work if there is a single value or multiple that are space separated.

Comment: You can `substitute substring-after()` where I was using `translate()` - but that would only be necessary if the values also contain `#` somewhere else in the value, and that probably would be bad if you are using that as a named anchor value.